# C++ analogue for -lspci command

Tags: c++, linux-device-driver

I need to search for Hardwares in linux environment based on Vendor IDs programmatically using C++.
I know that I can get the list using

> -lspci

Can anyone throw some light here??

Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: Just use lspci. There are some wrappers that can capture the output of the cmd in a string, google for it.

Comment: You could run `lspci` and parse the result ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `lspci` program uses `libpci` internally. Both the program and the library are part of the [pciutils](https://github.com/pciutils/pciutils) package. To use `libpci` programmatically from C or C++, I suggest taking a look at the [example](https://github.com/pciutils/pciutils/blob/master/example.c).

Comment: the example was exactly what I was looking for!